# What does "this probability density function is quadratic in x" mean?

Tags: probability

I'm reading a book on probabilistic robotics and it mentions that "this probability density function is quadratic in x."

I haven't heard of the phrase "quadratic in x" before. Can someone explain what it means? Does it mean that the graph has a quadratic shape?

Comment: Can you give some more context? (Out of context I would assume that it means you have a pdf of the form $(ax^2+bx+c) \chi_{[p,q]}(x)$ for some real numbers $a,b,c,p,q$.)

Comment: @Ian. Sorry I didn't add the context, but looks like null got the exact book, page and equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to *Thrun, Burgard, Fox: Probabilistic Robotics*.

Chapter 2.2, page 15, equation (2.4) is as follows:

> $$p(x)=\det(2\pi \Sigma)^{-\frac12} \exp \left\{ -\frac12 (x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\right\}$$

The text below states that :

> The argument in the exponent in this PDF is **quadratic in x**.

The chapter is titled "*Basic Concepts in Probability*" and the surrounding text is making sure that the simple mathematical concepts are clear, for example it is explained that:

> The superscript $^T$ marks the transpose of a vector.

Given that the mathematics are clear, the exponent can still be a bit intimidating, especially if one is not used to this notation that is common for multivariable equations and formulas.

Chances are a reader looks at the exponent

$$ -\frac12 (x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$$

and is entirely lost on what this is supposed to mean. So let's pretend this is a scalar equation (that is, there's only 1 dimension) and the variables take some simple values, like $\mu=0$ and $\Sigma = 1$

$$ -\frac12 (x-0)1(x-0)$$

$$ -\frac12 (x)(x)$$

$$ -\frac12 x^2$$

Now it is clear that the exponent is depending on (a function of) $x^2$. It's helpful to mention that because $x^2$ is nowhere to be seen in the exponent, but it's often helpful to have a qualitative understanding about the values one is working with.

The author wants to say that
"*Basically speaking, with all the mutli variable vector transposing mumbo jumbo aside, this thing depends on $x^2$*."

---

Also check out [robotics.SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) if you have other questions that are more related to robotics than the pure mathematics behind it.

Comment: Very nicely laid out.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for referencing the book. I wasn't sure if it would help.

Comment: @BrianTung thank you. Why increasing the number of dimensions is discussed so sparsely in mathematical education is beyond me. I first encountered it in a lecture on some technical application and it melted my brain, because nobody explained it. (and it still does whenever I encounter it) They let you stubbornly do some calculations by hand as if that prepares you for a formula like the one at hand. And then you get the feeling: "_What was all this math education for if I cannot handle this..._".  /end of rant =)

Comment: Hey @null, mind if I get your opinion. I really want to understand and build mobile robots. Would you recommend I go through this book sequentially understanding all the derivations before building out code, or writing code first and seeing how the parts are used then going back to understanding the derivations for the math? My current plan is to go the math route first.

Comment: @conman I didn't read the book, but I think I should read it one day. Math is a tool to build models of the real world, but they are never perfect. There's a lot more to building robots than just the math. There are so called "real world problems". Say for example you have some very nice code that predicts the position depending on the movement of the wheels with some freakishly complex math, which is rather useless when you encounter slip between the wheels and the ground. Sometimes it's easier to improve the system itself instead of the model thereof. My recommendation: do both alongside.